# tab character is not identified while parsing

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I have strings which have 2 tab characters as

```
# File contains multiple lines like this
'T1  Original 210 227    Extra Mile'
'T8  Modified 1646 1655   Tickets'
# Eg: "Tx" "indication" "start_index" "end_index" "word"
# 'T1\tOriginal 210 227\tExtra Mile'
```

I want the word after the second tab. so I am trying to find the index of '\t' and replace the initial string as empty.

```
def find_index(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]


def extract_words(filename):
    extracted_data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]
    search_key = '\t'
    for i in range(len(extracted_data)):
        indices = find_index(extracted_data[i], search_key)
        extracted_data[i] = extracted_data[i].replace(extracted_data[i][:indices[-1]], '')
    return extracted_data
```

but it does not identify the '\t' as indices output is []. 
what is causing the problem ?

the expected output

```
'Extra Mile'
'Tickets'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your lines do not contain tabs - hence no indexes, hence `IndexError`.
Use:

```
if len(indices)>1:  # only extract by slicing if indexes found!
```

to check for that.

---

Why so complex? Use [`str.split("\t")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
def extract_words(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

    k = []
    for l in lines:
        try: 
            k.append(l.split("\t")[2]) 
        except IndexError:
            print (f"no 2 tabs in '{l}'")
    return k

t = """T1\tOriginal 210 227\tExtra Mile
T8\tModified 1646 1655\tTickets
Error\ttext"""


fn = "t.txt"
with open(fn,"w") as f: 
    f.write(t)

print(*extract_words(fn), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
no 2 tabs in 'Error text'
Extra Mile
Tickets
```

This will work on lines with 2 tabs and report any that do not have those.